# fwrite() keeps writing 00s in Unix. Where might be wrong?

Tags: c, linux, unix

My part of the code looks like this:

```
for(i=0; i<16;i++){
    for(j=0;j<16;j++){
        printf(" %d ", microBlock[i][j]);   // everything looks ok from the console
    }
    printf("\n");
}
for(i=0; i<16;i++)
    for(j=0;j<16;j++){
        fwrite(&microBlock[i][j], 1, 1, output);  //each value is smaller than 255
                                        //only want to write 1 byte for each value. 
                                        // For example, ff for value 255
    }
```

I want to write out the values of that 16 by 16 array (All values are Integer and smaller than 255) to a file. But it keeps writing 00s to file instead of values in array under Unix(Working on my Linux machine but when I upload to one of lab machine using Unix, the output file just filled with 00s) Does anyone know where might be wrong in my code? Thanks.

PS: I know Unix and Linux may have some differences but my code is really simple. Does it really matter?

Comment: If by "integer", you mean `int`, then note that `sizeof(int)` probably isn't 1.

Comment: If you declare `int microBlock[16][16];` then you should be able to use `fwrite(microBlock, sizeof(microBlock[0][0]), 16 * 16, output);` and you can check that it succeeded by testing that the return value is 256 (which is 16 * 16).  If the `microBlock` matrix is wider than 16 (so the second dimension is larger than 16), then you need a loop to write the first 16 entries of each row (in a single `fwrite()`) for each of the first 16 rows.

Comment: The problem is if I use sizeof, the output will write 4 bytes for each value in the array (ff 00 00 00). But I only need "ff", no padding 0s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have:

```
int microBlock[16][16];
```

and it is populated with values in the range 0x00..0xFF, and you only want to write a single byte for each of those values to the file, then you need to do one of two things:

#### Option 1 — write a byte at a time

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
    {
        char byte = microBlock[i][j];
        if (fwrite(&byte), 1, 1, output) != 1)
            ...write failed...
    }
}
```

#### Option 2 — write all the bytes at one time

```
char nanoBlock[16][16];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        nanoBlock[i][j] = microBlock[i][j];

if (fwrite(nanoBlock, sizeof(nanoBlock), 1, output) != 1)
    ...write failed...
```

Either will work; the second is likely to be more efficient because it makes just one call to `fwrite()`, but it is not an absolute given.

Answer (score 2):

Size of `int` certainly isn't 1. Use the correct size:

```
fwrite(&microBlock[i][j], sizeof( microBlock[i][j] ), 1, output);
```

Comment: It really write 4 bytes for each, and each value need to be stored in hexdecimal, in that case, only 1 byte. If I use sizeof(int), the output looks like this for each value in the array: ff 00 00 00 when the value is 255. What if I only want to write ff for each value without padding 0s

Comment: @user1726119 I suggest asking a new question.